# Removing elements from a document in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Working on building this to-do list app to learn JS better.

I am able to insert text into box and have it add a new div element to the page with the relevant text residing within the div. The code that adds the div to the page automatically applies the class `.newItem` then adds an incrementing id *`i0`, `i1`, `i2`, etc* each time it's clicked. Everything works without an issue. Now, I have been fiddling around with the code to be able to click a single div element and have it remove itself from the page, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
var iDN = 0;
//Function that adds a new div with a custom incrementing id number
document.getElementById('add_button').onclick = function () {
    var taskName = document.getElementById('add_task').value; // Store the value in the textbox into a variable
    document.querySelector('.shit_to_do').innerHTML += '<div class = "newItem" id = "i' + iDN + '"' + 'onclick = removeEl()' + '>' + taskName + '</div>';
    iDN += 1;
};

document.getElementById('testing').onclick = function () {
    var parentNode = document.querySelector('.shit_to_do');
    parentNode.removeChild(parentNode.children[0]);
}

function removeEl() {
    for (i = 0; i < iDN; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById('i' + i).onclick) {
            document.getElementById('i' + i).display.style = 'none';
        }
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

The for loop was really some random option I was trying to figure out how things were working onclick for each div, but didn't get to far with that one.

tl;dr:
I want to add click events to the new divs added onto the page in a single, universal function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `document.getElementById('i' + i).onclick` will be `null` if you've not set a handler to this attribute/property, otherwise it will be a *function*. `null` is always *falsy*, a *function* is always *truthy*.

To remove your element, you'll either have to look at [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) or [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target) where `e` is the click *event*, and then call the DOM method `node.removeChild(child)`.

---

The *"quick and dirty"* solution is to pass `this` into `removeEl` and remove it that way,

```
// ...
    document.querySelector('.shit_to_do').innerHTML += '<div class="newItem" id="i' + iDN + '" onclick="removeEl(this)">' + taskName + '</div>';
// ...
function removeEl(elm) {
    elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm);
}
```

*I also removed the strange spacing between attribute names and values in your HTML*

---

A *perhaps "cleaner"* solution is to create your nodes and attach listeners all by using *DOM* methods

```
function createDiv(index, taskname) {
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.setAttribute('id', 'i' + index);
    d.textContent = taskname;
    return d;
}

function removeElm() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}

var iDN = 0;
document.getElementById('add_button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var taskName = document.getElementById('add_task').value,
        list = querySelector('.shit_to_do'),
        div = createDiv(iDN, taskName);
    div.addEventListener('click', removeElm);
    list.appendChild(div);
    iDN += 1;
});
```

This way means the browser does not re-parse any *HTML* as it not use [`element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML), which is a dangerous property may destroy references etc (along with usually being a bit slower)

---

Helpful links

- [`node.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)
- [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement)
- [`node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

Comment: @ryan Please also consider the second example

Comment: Just curious as to why this wouldn't work. alert(elm.parentNode.children[elm].innerHTML); How would I be able to return the text residing inside the div to an alert box?

Comment: Nevermind, I see I could just do elm.innerHTML